# Use Open weather map in MVC Visual studios

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, api, openweathermap

We are two students who want to use Open Weather Map in our school project. To create a model of the received information from the application about the weather we have to create a model just like the one Open weather map uses. This is what the received json string looks like:

{"coord":{"lon":103.85,"lat":1.29},"weather":[{"id":803,"main":"Clouds","description":"broken clouds","icon":"04n"}],"base":"stations","main":{"temp":302.39,"pressure":1008,"humidity":83,"temp_min":301.15,"temp_max":303.15},"visibility":10000,"wind":{"speed":3.6,"deg":180},"clouds":{"all":75},"dt":1495107000,"sys":{"type":1,"id":8146,"message":0.0229,"country":"SG","sunrise":1495061739,"sunset":1495105587},"id":1880252,"name":"Singapore","cod":200}

And this is what I get by using the URL for singapore:

http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=singapore&APPID=******

My question is, does anyone know the exact data types for all the information? Do we have to create a model to receive the api information? 
Then we have to deserialize the string.

Comment: You can paste a full sample of data into json2csharp which will give you class structure, and data types. http://json2csharp.com/ Or use Visual Studio directly with "Edit -> Paste Special -> Paste JSON as C#"

Comment: Nice! Thank you :) So I could surely use this and it will be exactly the same data types as the original ones?

Comment: See my below answer

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the JSON response format is in their documentation [here](http://openweathermap.org/current#current_JSON).  Goes over each individual value and tells you what it is, which should let you create a class or otherwise map it to C# code.  Also gives you the values for some of the fields (main.temp can be in Kelvin, Celcius, or Fahrenheit).

And I would assume you'd have to create some sort of model in C# to represent the parsed JSON data if you want to use it.  I would start with each numeric field, figuring out the best type to represent them.  Then I'd add the string fields, such as the country code.  Then for fields that have a set number of values (ex: main.temp) I'd have them as a separate Enum, so that field can only be one of the valid values.

Comment: Thank you! We will definitely be using that link. So it doesn't matter what data types I use for the different parameters? I guess we could just choose int64 for longitude but we are not really sure, I thought we had to use the exact same data types as they do.

Comment: You don't _have_ to, as long as your data type can handle every value they may provide.  It's good practice to try to map the types to be as close as possible to the possible values, though.  As an extreme example, if the range of values they provided for one of the fields was 0 to 255, you could use a `long` but a much better idea would be to use a `byte`, because it more accurately reflects the data range.

Comment: Upvoted. Downvoting an answer and providing absolutely no comment as to why it was downvoted is counterproductive to an answer that actually provides benefit or insight to OP.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your final question first,

> Do we have to create a model to receive the api information?

No, but is it recommended to? Yes.
Having a strongly typed class, instead of using something such as `dynamic`, allows you to get compile time checking instead of waiting for a potential spelling mistake, or an invalid cast, to bomb out and result in a runtime error.

To create your classes, as mentioned in my comment, you can use json2csharp which will use types according to the actual JSON sample which you have provided.

Below is the class mappings for the JSON string which you have provided,

```
public class Rootobject
{
    public Coord coord { get; set; }
    public Weather[] weather { get; set; }
    public string _base { get; set; }
    public Main main { get; set; }
    public int visibility { get; set; }
    public Wind wind { get; set; }
    public Clouds clouds { get; set; }
    public int dt { get; set; }
    public Sys sys { get; set; }
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int cod { get; set; }
}

public class Coord
{
    public float lon { get; set; }
    public float lat { get; set; }
}

public class Main
{
    public float temp { get; set; }
    public int pressure { get; set; }
    public int humidity { get; set; }
    public float temp_min { get; set; }
    public float temp_max { get; set; }
}

public class Wind
{
    public float speed { get; set; }
    public int deg { get; set; }
}

public class Clouds
{
    public int all { get; set; }
}

public class Sys
{
    public int type { get; set; }
    public int id { get; set; }
    public float message { get; set; }
    public string country { get; set; }
    public int sunrise { get; set; }
    public int sunset { get; set; }
}

public class Weather
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string main { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string icon { get; set; }
}
```

With this, you can then deserialize the Json to an Object using something such as JSON.NET, which I use in the following code snippet.

```
class Program
{
    // Our JSON Sample
    private static string JsonSample =
            "{\"coord\":{\"lon\":103.85,\"lat\":1.29},\"weather\":[{\"id\":803,\"main\":\"Clouds\",\"description\":\"broken clouds\",\"icon\":\"04n\"}],\"base\":\"stations\",\"main\":{\"temp\":302.39,\"pressure\":1008,\"humidity\":83,\"temp_min\":301.15,\"temp_max\":303.15},\"visibility\":10000,\"wind\":{\"speed\":3.6,\"deg\":180},\"clouds\":{\"all\":75},\"dt\":1495107000,\"sys\":{\"type\":1,\"id\":8146,\"message\":0.0229,\"country\":\"SG\",\"sunrise\":1495061739,\"sunset\":1495105587},\"id\":1880252,\"name\":\"Singapore\",\"cod\":200}"
        ;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Deserialize into our RootObject
        Rootobject rootObject = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(JsonSample);

        Console.WriteLine(rootObject.name); // Prints Singapore

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh nice!!!!! We will try to use that, it might take a few days when we get to that point of the laboration but thank you so much for your time! :D I'll comment when we get there!!

Comment: It was very useful! We managed to get around all that and create a javascript in the view and to set the url manually to get the information :) With help from the things you wrote! Thank you :)

Comment: Good to hear you have gotten it working, please do mark an answer to help others browsing for similar help.